# When you `git show` on a merge commit, what does the diff mean?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff

When I `git show` on a merge commit, it usually shows no diff, but sometimes, it shows a small diff.  What is it showing me?  My guess would be that it's showing how any conflicts were resolved.

Comment: What does the diff output look like?

Comment: See the [`git show` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show): *For commits it shows the log message and textual diff. It also presents the merge commit in a special format as produced by **`git diff-tree --cc`**.* (my emphasis)

Answer (score 2):

`git show` on a merge commit uses the [combined diff format](http://git-scm.com/docs/diff-format) which omits files in which both parents agree. A merge commit that did not have any conflicts does not "add" any information. However, when you do have conflicts and  you resolve them, the changes are staged and committed as part of the merge commit, which as you have already stated in your question is the reason they appear.

If you look at the `git show` on a merge commit, you will see a line like this:

```
Merge: 213bbc0 5c1c166
```

You can have a look at the diff using (note that I reversed the commits):

```
git diff 5c1c166..213bbc0
```

This may be the command you were actually looking for when you tried using `git show` on the merge commit.